# Arduino Nano + HC-05 : AT+INQ gives corrupted output

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, at-command

I'm working with Arduino Nano + HC-05 Bluetooth + ENC28J60 Ethernet module. Using [EtherCard.h from JeeLabs.net](https://github.com/jcw/ethercard). I have some issues reading from the Bluetooth module.

Bluetooth module is set to AT mode (Holding the button down with a clip / Giving 5V into the pin 34. Tried both ways)

Here are my configurations:

```
ROLE=1
CMODE=1
INQM=1,5,23
```

And here is the `loop()` and its related functions

```cpp
static uint32_t timer;

void loop () {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() >= timer) {
    if (BTScan()) {
      sendRequest(); // Send HTTP POST with `deviceBT` using EtherCard
    }
  }
}

String deviceBT = "";

bool BTScan() {
  bluetooth.listen();

  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    deviceBT = "";

    String readstr = bluetooth.readString();
    readstr.trim();

    if (readstr == PSTR("ERROR:(16)")) {
      Serial.println(F("BLUETOOTH NOT INITIALIZED\nBLUETOOTH INIT:"));
      bluetooth.println(F("AT+INIT"));
      if (bluetooth.find(F("OK"))) Serial.println(F("OK"));
    } else if (readstr.length() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);  delay(200);
      }
      if (readstr.indexOf(F("+INQ:")) > -1) {
        Serial.println(F("BLUETOOTH FOUND:"));
        Serial.println(readstr);
        deviceBT = readstr;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  Serial.println(F("BLUETOOTH INQUIRE START:"));
  bluetooth.println(F("AT+INQ"));
  timer = millis() + 5000;

  return false;
}
```

Assuming my Bluetooth ID is 303A:64:9A65CD
And the program responds this via serial.

```
BLUETOOTH INQUIRE START:
BLUETOOTH FOUND:
OK
+INQ:303A:è4:9A<5CD,2010C,7FFC

// sometimes
BLUETOOTH FOUND:
gK
+INQ:303A:6::9A85F¢,2010C,7FFF

// some other time
BLUETOOTH FOUND:
+INQ:303A:64:9C<5FD,20˜0C,7FFF
```

The Bluetooth works fine in another program without the Ethernet part, the physical installations are both the same.

All of my sketch uses 17,664 bytes (57%) and global variables use 984 bytes (48%)

Please help. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found myself a workaround, or maybe it is the solution.

In the `loop()` function, I added a little delay of `500ms` after the call to `ether.packetLoop()` and it seems to work.

Not sure if there are any side effects on this since I am an absolute newbie on this kind of programming.

```cpp
void loop () {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  delay(500); // Add 500ms delay to the loop

  if (millis() >= timer) {
    if (BTScan()) {
      sendRequest(); // Send HTTP POST with `deviceBT` using EtherCard
    }
  }
}
```

Please correct me if I'm not.